# Decision Trees with Logloss and SMOTE

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret

I am working through some decision trees with the data from the [Kaggle Walmart competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-trip-type-classification) and I am running into a couple errors. I was successful last week with running the trees in rpart, but now I am using caret to incorporate logloss and smote for overclassification. Below are is my code and the respective errors:

```
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2))
train <- data[ind==1,]
test <- data[ind==2,]
########################
#Building a new DT with logloss and CV
########################

ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5, classProbs=TRUE, 
summaryFunction=mnLogLoss)

ll_tree <- train(TripType~., data=train, method="rpart",  metric="logLoss", 
trControl=ctrl)

Error in ctrl$summaryFunction(testOutput, lev, method) : 
  'data' should have columns consistent with 'lev'
In addition: Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  cannnot compute class probabilities for regression


###################
#Using SMOTE
###################
ctrl2 <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5, classProbs=TRUE, 
summaryFunction=mnLogLoss, sampling = "smote")
smote_tree <- train(TripType~., data=train, trControl=ctrl2, method="rpart")

Error: sampling methods are only implemented for classification problems
```

Any help would be appreciated as this is my first time trying this.

Thanks

Comment: `TripType` is not a factor, convert it to one with `TripType <- as.factor(TripType)`. The problem is that `caret` is seeing the task as a regression. If still does not work please make a reproducible example and supply a sample of the data.

Comment: @missuse if you don't mind me asking, where should I do that? How should I set it up? Would you mind showing an example? Thanks!

Comment: Just before you run any codes you posted, run `data$TripType <- as.factor(data$TripType)` and try to train.

Comment: When I did that, I got the error 'Error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X12, X14, X15, X18, X19, X20, X21, X22, X23, X24, X25, X26, X27, X28, X29, X30, X31, X32, X33, X34, X35, X36, X37, X38, X39, X40, X41, X42, X43, X44, X999 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).'

Comment: the error is pretty much self explanatory , you can try to change the class names to something like: `data$TripType <- as.factor(paste0("class_", data$TripType))`.